# MacOS installation LLVM

Tags: macos, clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang

I'm new with llvm and I have a problem with it. I have installed it with command `brew install llvm`

after I did this `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

After this I wrote `hello world` example which is located in `/Documents/llvm_exmaple/helloworld.ll` and this `.ll` and when I typed `lli helloworld.ll` I got message like `-bash: lli: command not found`.

What should I write to make it work? By the way other commands don't work too. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it after this command `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` you should write this `source ~/.bash_profile` and after everything will be work correctly